# How to response from servlet to YUI?

Tags: servlets

I send io to server with YUI and how to respond back to YUI?
Here is code :

```
var user = {
                   userName:   username,
                   password:   password,
                   customerId: customerId
                  };

           var success = function (ioId, o) {
               responseContent   = Y.JSON.parse(o.responseText);
               if (responseContent.code == 0) {
                     window.location = 'Home.jsp';
                  }
           };
           var failure = function (ioId, o) {
                 //do something
              };
           var cfg = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    sync: false,
                    data: user,
                    on:      {
                        'success': success,
                        'failure': failure
                     }
           };

           new Y.IO().send("http://localhost:7778/web/LoginController", cfg);
```

Redirect not work and i decide to redirect by YUI. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var success = function (ioId, o) {
           responseContent   = Y.JSON.parse(o.responseText);
           if (responseContent.code == 0) {
                 window.location = 'Home.jsp';
              }


             //Like this?
             responseDiv.innerHTML = responseContent.yourData;
       };
```

Comment: I dont know how to repond data to page from servlet(not in page).

Comment: can you do an example of what you want to do?